# Reading a .csv file faster than reading same file compressed as .gz

Tags: java, gzip, inputstream, reader

Seems a bit ironic, but when I was reading a 2GB .csv file line by line using BufferedReader, it took around 4.5 seconds. I compressed the file with gzip which came to around 230MB. I used GZIPInputStream wrapped with a BufferedReader to read the .gz file. It took around 8.5 seconds.

I am aware that InputStream interface reads bytes of data as opposed to Readers, but I assumed that if a 200MB file would prove faster to be loaded onto the memory. Is it possible for better performance to be achieved using .gz? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GZIPInputStream is unzipping the file as it is reading it in.
There is some overhead to decompressing that would explain the extra time taken.

Comment: Yes that's my suspicion too. My query is whether we can somehow perform better with reading the compressed file. I tried tinkering with the buffer size but it did not help. I assumed compression is an IO intensive task hence it would not hamper CPU task time. Plz correct me if I am assuming wrongly.

Comment: Compression strains CPU more. You are basically trading the space on disc for increased CPU usage

Answer (score 0):

How much time does it take for your computer to decompress the file? May i guess about `8.5 - 4.5 = 4` seconds? I guess that is one reason for the the extra time it takes.